# Managing MBeans in a cluster using JMX

Tags: java, jmx

I am going through the spring support for JMX. I found configuring and managing MBeans quite easy. Just wanted to know, if there are multiple nodes/servers and I would have to manage the MBeans across the cluster using JMX, how to do accomplish that.

Would be thankful if there is any blog which explains me the same. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the OpenDMK, which supports cascading (federating). There's a [mavenized build](https://github.com/nickman/OpenDMK) as well.

Comment: Thank you Ross. I was not aware of this, will have a look at it